# Can a foreign key be optional

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relation

```
Table employee
{
employeename  //employeename is unique
}

Table job
{
jobid,job,assignedPerson,status
}
```

assignedPerson is a foreign key that references to employeename(employee)
What I want is to know how to delete an employee record without having to remove his record from the job table i.e. I mean I want to keep the job record and see which person was assigned the job even if that person is no longer an employee..

```
Table employee
{
employeename
}

Table jobemployee
{
jobid,assignedPerson
}

Table job
{
jobid,job,status
}
```

Even if I do this I will have to delete the record from jobemployee if I want to delete the record of employee from 'employee' table and will not be able to know which person was assigned the job..
Please help..

Comment: You must to create a colunm in job table that will store the name of employee, or create a special table to store only the names and keys of employees, and create a link when some record be deleted.

Comment: What if I remove the foreign key constraint from assignedPerson as I am using the employee table to show all the records stored in it and making user to select a record. the selected record has to be one from the employee table. and then I am adding the selected employeeName to the assignedPerson to particular job.. So the assigned person has to be one from the employee table record.. so even if i remove the foreign key constraint there wudn't be any problem. Correct? and it would be easy to delete the employee record and still keep the assignedPerson record in 'job table.. Am I right?

Comment: Dropping the foreign key and deleting employee records will come back to haunt you.  You describe the problem yourself at the end of your question.  The unique constraint on names isn't necessarily a good idea either.

Comment: @DanBracuk What I must do then?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to add a flag to the Employee table for `deleted`.

A workaround is to add a column `assignedNonEmployee` to the `job` table.  Before you delete an `employee`, you set the `assignedPerson` column to `null`, and copy its value into the `assignedNonEmployee` column.  Since the later column has no foreign key constraint, you are now allowed to delete the `employee` record.

Comment: What if I remove the foreign key constraint from assignedPerson as I am using the employee table to show all the records stored in it and making user to select a record. the selected record has to be one from the employee table. and then I am adding the selected employeeName to the assignedPerson to particular job.. So the assigned person has to be one from the employee table record.. so even if i remove the foreign key constraint there wudn't be any problem. Correct? and it would be easy to delete the employee record and still keep the assignedPerson record in 'job table.. Am I right?

Comment: That seems appropriate in your case.  But removing constraints invites inconsistencies, like a mismatch between the employee's name in the job and employee tables.  That's why it's not recommended.